# "Tag plus something else" search looks ugly on beta sites when the tag wiki excerpt contains the tag name

Tags: bug, design, search, tag-search

Searching for a [tag-name], plus some other criteria, results in an ugly tag information box which seems to show HTML tags treated as text, rather than as HTML.

Here's an example: [search Writing for [non-fiction] is:a](https://writing.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bnon-fiction%5D+is%3Aa) and look at the tag description box:

[image: Screenshot]

With a quick sampling I was unable to reproduce this on other beta sites, but I've also been unable to quickly identify a tag that actually uses the tag name itself within the tag wiki excerpt, which seems very related.